# Nested axis labels in altair plot?

Tags: python, altair

It it possible to create nested in altair, similar to this from the `ggh4x` package?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [facet charts](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/compound_charts.html#faceted-charts). You might have to fiddle around with the configurations of the titles, but in essence, that should give you what you want.

Comment: I am rather trying to figure out if something like [this vega lite example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74231700/nested-axis-labels-for-grouped-bar-chart-in-vega-lite) is possible in altair, too.

Comment: Isn't that just [this](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart_horizontal.html#horizontal-grouped-bar-chart)?

Comment: But how would you do that, if you need multiple levels (i.e. faceting and nested axis labels)?